# React-native-gifted-chat image not showing

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

My image is not showing up. [image: My database]

This is the message in firebase.

```
messages={this.state.messages}
          onSend={FirebaseStorage.shared.send}
          user={this.user}
          renderMessageImage={() => this.showImage}
          renderUsernameOnMessage
```

And that is the render code. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check how you are getting the messages. Are you getting the image?